# Is the solution of $dy (3x + \cos(x)) + dx (3y-y \sin(x))=0$ be $3xy + y \cos(x) = C$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, solution-verification

Could you please check my work of solving $dy (3x + \cos(x)) + dx (3y-y \sin(x))=0$?

[image]

Am I correct?

THANKS!

Comment: Yes [it's correct](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%283x+%2B+cos%28x%29%29dy+%2B+%283y-y+sin%28x%29%29+dx+%3D0)

Comment: @Utkarsh Thanks.